# Replace column with rows pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

How do I reshape pivot(using pandas):

```
          0         1       \
trans -0.521058 -0.521058    
serie -0.521816 -0.521816   
recor -0.468133 -0.468133
```

to:

```
        trans       serie       recor                
0     -0.521058    -0.521816    -0.468133   
1     -0.521058    -0.521816    -0.468133
```

Bonus:

How do I append several columns into one datafarme.

I used :

```
df = df.append(oneCol)
```

and I receive the first table

*sorry for the spacing

Thanks

Comment: What... this is a simple transposition. `df = df.T`... did that not work?

Comment: No I just tried it..
edit: sorry you were right it worked
Thanks!